# Word for describing something that causes seizures?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that describes an object that would cause an epileptic seizure?  In a similar way that something that causes an allergy attack is an allergen  For example, the flashing lights in the game were _____.  The closest thing I can think of is possibly "triggering" but that isn't very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term of art is "epileptogenic," but this term is slightly misleading because it encompasses only seizures arising from epilepsy, which is neurological disorder.  Sometimes normal brains can go into seizure, so the more general term  is "ictogenic," from the Latin *icere*, to strike.  For a medical exposition, see [Seizures and Epilepsy](https://books.google.com/books?id=5PgjmjugIX8C&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=seizure%20causing%20term%20epileptogenic&source=bl&ots=7_rWYBeB72&sig=SmRU1jD5Q0EG1StN7sGkkomgP64&hl=en&sa=X&ei=omWhVdPhFoiAygSp6YTQCw&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=seizure%20causing%20term%20epileptogenic&f=false) by Jerome Engel.

Comment: True, but if you wanted to be understood by ordinary mortals, you might do better saying something like *the flashing lights were **fit-inducing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or *seizure triggers*.

Comment: Some of us are operating on a higher plane, but point taken.  "Fit-inducing" might err on the side of the sublunary though.

Comment: @deadrat: But (particularly, for *learners*) it does have the advantage of being a ***productive*** mechanism (*vomit-inducing, anxiety-inducing,* etc.). Possibly there's even a dedicated word for *yawn-inducing*, say, but who wants to learn all those when you can just apply a simple rule? Teach a man to fish, and all that.

Comment: Besides, I don't think many people would look down on [*epilepsy-inducing*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22epilepsy+inducing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for OP's context, and few would understand the concept of "non-epilectic fits" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An English phrase would be "seizure-inducing".

Answer (score 0):

Numerous web dictionaries and wikis define `convulsant` as an agent, usually a drug, that induces seizures. An `anticonvulsant` is a drug used to treat seizures.